# getting key_type from value_type

Tags: c++, templates, std

I have a class X that operates on std containers. A function that takes a value_type as argument must call a function that takes a key_type as argument. How do I do that? I seems so basic.

```
template<typename C>
class X
{
  void foo(typename C::value_type vt)
  {
    bar(vt.first); // this works for C = std::map
    bar(vt); // this works for C = std::set
  }
  void bar(typename C::key_type kt)
  {
     ...
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a (`private`) `bar` overload that is a function template and takes a `T::value_type` as argument.

```
template<typename C>
class X
{
public:
  void foo(typename C::value_type vt)
  {
    bar(vt);
  }

  void bar(typename C::key_type kt)
  {}

private:
  template<typename T = C>
  void bar(typename T::value_type kt)
  {
     bar(kt.first);
  }
};
```

When `C` is an `std::map`, the call to `bar` within `foo` will resolve to the member function template, and it'll then call other `bar` with the correct argument.

When `C` is an `std::set`, the call to `bar` will match both the `bar` overloads, but since one is a member function template, and the other isn't, the latter will be considered a better match.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ce15a3079bb4402)